# JS runtime environment

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, tdd, client-side, spine.js

I'm new in JavaScript, so excuse me if this question is not worth asking.
I need a JavaScript Runtime Environment with some features:

- Command line interface
- Coffee Script compability
- Possibility of unit-testing(By the way, what can yo say about unit-testing frameworks?)

My OS is ubuntu 12.04, and I'm not sure node.js is worth installation(May be it should be used?). I have read about google's [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/), but I'm not sure whether it is used in a such way.

P.S. I'm going to develop client-side sctipts with coffee and Spine. The server is Python(Django,WebPy) or PHP(Symfony2, Silex).

Great thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't use Coffee before learning JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install **node.js**, **npm**, and then **coffee-script**.

Now you can run coffeescript at the command line via the `coffee` executable. Run it with no commands to have an interactive prompt, or give it a filename to execute a `.coffee` file.

As for testing, any JS testing framework will work.  There are a bunch. [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) is one of my favorites.